# How to add div to the correct position when there is a new sql entry?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax

I have coded a pizza order system and my table looks like this:

```
id, userid, timeorderd, readyin, processed.
```

An example entry is:

```
1, 1, 11:00:00, 10, 0
```

User with id 1 ordered a pizza at 11:00:00 o'clock and wants the pizza to be finished in 10 minutes and the status is, that the pizza is not ready yet.

I now want a listener script for the pizza service that is waiting for a new order. First, it should get all entries with status 0 (those with status 1 will be deleted). It then should calculate the time when the pizza should be ready (timeordered + readyin) and sort the array in that order.

Now if a new mysql entry is in the database, it should add a div at the correct position. e.g. there is an order that should be ready in 5min and one that should be ready in 60min. now, when there is a new order that should be ready in 30min, the new div should go between the two others.

Comment: Can you show any code? That would help a lot!

Comment: It could be easily solved with some server-side programming. You could have a controller method that returns a JSON response. That could be processed with an ajax-function, which creates the divs dynamically ...

Answer (score 0):

you could order the data divs by using the sql "ORDER BY" key word in sql example

```
SELECT pizza FROM table_name ORDER BY tie remaining time column_table_name;
```

and use ajax to reorder the divs using the setInterval() in java script

Comment: the mysql query isnt that problem. ajax is the problem if this is the way how i could do this

Comment: There is no code yet. I dont know how this should work. Should i run an ajax script evey minute?

Comment: well there should be a  ajax function to grab the datas from php. to call a function there should be an event or "setInterval" function to call the function to update the dom

Comment: one suggestion to order the div perfectly you could insert the time using the time() in php so it would be easy for php to sort the array accordingly..